# Might be a bug in Pandas. Should I report it? And How?

Tags: debugging, pandas

Dataframe like so:

```
view = {'objectid' : [474479]*5,
    'n' : [1, 3, 4, 5,6]}
```

After running:

```
view['n'][10] = 5
```

Any further changes don't 'stick'.  i.e.:

```
view['n'][4] = 1000
view['n'][1] = 7
```

Returns:

```
view
   n, objectid
0, 1, 474479
1, 2, 474479
2, 3, 474479
3, 4, 474479
4, 5, 474479
```

I don't know protocol for a situation like this. First that there's no out of index range error and second, that future updates don't work *really* seem like bugs to me. But, I'm such a new time programmer I feel like I should post this on stackoverflow first to make sure this is appropriate, and if so, what (if anything) I should do about it.

Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a warning about this in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html):

> Whether a copy or a reference is returned for a setting operation, may
>   depend on the context. This is sometimes called chained assignment and
>   should be avoided. See [Returning a View versus Copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

`view['n']` is returning a copy of the Series, not a view. So (despite the variable name) modification of the copy does not affect the original DataFrame, `view`.

Since it is hard to predict what expressions return a copy or a view, "chained assignments" are to be avoided. Instead, assign to an indexer like `loc` or `ix`:

```
In [79]: view.ix[0, 'n'] = 999

In [80]: view
Out[80]: 
     n  objectid
0  999    474479
1    3    474479
2    4    474479
3    5    474479
4    6    474479

In [81]: view.ix[10, 'n'] = 5

In [82]: view
Out[82]: 
      n  objectid
0   999    474479
1     3    474479
2     4    474479
3     5    474479
4     6    474479
10    5       NaN
```

---

PS. [Pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas) is developed on github. If in the future you do find a bug, you can [report the issue there](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues?direction=desc&milestone=18&sort=created&state=closed).